# How to expand and collapse table row on click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I was learning from this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows?file=app%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html) how to create a expandable Table.
I'm a newbie with angular.
What I want to do is when I click at the same row I can expand the row and when I click again at the same row I can collapse it.

Any suggestion of what I can do to add this functionality?

Comment: Please post some code example of what you did and what you are trying to achieve but doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, you can use an accordion to do that or better still create one for yourself by defining a variable with an collapsed height which will be be altered on expanded. then use inline angular style to dynamically control the height

Comment: refer Collapse in bootsrap...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `(click)` event you are only setting `expandedElement` so it will always get selected. You need to instead toggle the value so the row can be deselected as well.

Change your `(click)` function to the following

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
         matRipple 
         class="element-row" 
         [class.expanded]="expandedElement == row"
         (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === row ? null : row">
</mat-row>
```